# How I can prove that $f:[0,1]^{r+1}→ℝ^{r+1}$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following real analytic function: $f:ℝ^{r+1}→ℝ^{r+1}$. We will consider only the restriction $f: [0,1]^{r+1}→ℝ^{r+1}$.
My **question** is: How I can prove that $f: [0,1]^{r+1}→ℝ^{r+1}$ is bounded?

Comment: @Abel: The question was edited.

Comment: I see. I will provide an answer to your new question.

Comment: @ADC that function is not defined for $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @ADC: Where does that map take $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the original question:

First of all, bijections between $(0,1)^{r+1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{r+1}$ have nothing to do with space filling curves. The latter are bijections between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^2$. Furthermore, you can't prove that any continuous $f\colon (0,1)^{r+1}\to\mathbb{R}^{r+1}$ is bounded exactly because it could easily be a bijection and therefore surjective...

Answer (score 2):

Since $[0,1]^{r+1}$ is closed and bounded as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{r+1}$ it is compact.
Furthermore, continuous images of compact sets are compact, so for any continuous function $f\colon [0,1]^{r+1}\to\mathbb{R}^{r+1}$, $\mathrm{im}(f) = f([0,1]^{r+1})$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^{r+1}$ and hence closed and bounded.